# Query Rule for non-indexed attribute FILTER

Tags: arangodb

I observere an enormous runtime difference between those two AQL statements an a DB set with about 20 Mio records:

```
FOR e IN EAll
    FILTER e.lastname == "Kmp"  // <-- skip-index
    FILTER e.lastpaff != ""     // <-- no index
RETURN e
// runs in less than a second
```

AND

```
FOR e IN EAll
    FILTER e.lastpaff != ""     // <-- no index
    FILTER e.lastname == "Kmp"  // <-- skip-index
RETURN e
// needs about a minute to execute.
```

In addition to be (or not) indexed, the selectivity of those statements is highly different: the indexedAttribute is highly selective where-as the nonIndexedAttribute only filters 50%.

Is it possible that there is not yet an optimization rule for that? I currently am using ArangoDB 2.4.0.

**DETAILS:**

There is a SKIP-Index on the indexed Attribute (which seems to be used in the execuation plan 1).
Here are the execuation plan, in which only the order of the filters are changed:

```
    FAST QUERY:

    arangosh [Uni]> stmt.explain()
    {
      "plan" : {
        "nodes" : [
          {
            "type" : "SingletonNode",
            "dependencies" : [ ],
            "id" : 1,
            "estimatedCost" : 1,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 1
          },
          {
            "type" : "IndexRangeNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              1
            ],
            "id" : 8,
            "estimatedCost" : 170463.32,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 170462,
            "database" : "Uni",
            "collection" : "EAll",
            "outVariable" : {
              "id" : 0,
              "name" : "i"
            },
            "ranges" : [
              [
                {
                  "variable" : "i",
                  "attr" : "lastname",
                  "lowConst" : {
                    "bound" : "Kmp",
                    "include" : true,
                    "isConstant" : true
                  },
                  "highConst" : {
                    "bound" : "Kmp",
                    "include" : true,
                    "isConstant" : true
                  },
                  "lows" : [ ],
                  "highs" : [ ],
                  "valid" : true,
                  "equality" : true
                }
              ]
            ],
            "index" : {
              "type" : "skiplist",
              "id" : "13295598550318",
              "unique" : false,
              "fields" : [
                "lastname"
              ]
            },
            "reverse" : false
          },
          {
            "type" : "CalculationNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              8
            ],
            "id" : 5,
            "estimatedCost" : 340925.32,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 170462,
            "expression" : {
              "type" : "compare !=",
              "subNodes" : [
                {
                  "type" : "attribute access",
                  "name" : "lastpaff",
                  "subNodes" : [
                    {
                      "type" : "reference",
                      "name" : "i",
                      "id" : 0
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "type" : "value",
                  "value" : ""
                }
              ]
            },
            "outVariable" : {
              "id" : 2,
              "name" : "2"
            },
            "canThrow" : false
          },
          {
            "type" : "FilterNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              5
            ],
            "id" : 6,
            "estimatedCost" : 511387.32,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 170462,
            "inVariable" : {
              "id" : 2,
              "name" : "2"
            }
          },
          {
            "type" : "ReturnNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              6
            ],
            "id" : 7,
            "estimatedCost" : 681849.3200000001,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 170462,
            "inVariable" : {
              "id" : 0,
              "name" : "i"
            }
          }
        ],
        "rules" : [
          "move-calculations-up",
          "move-filters-up",
          "move-calculations-up-2",
          "move-filters-up-2",
          "use-index-range",
          "remove-filter-covered-by-index"
        ],
        "collections" : [
          {
            "name" : "EAll",
            "type" : "read"
          }
        ],
        "variables" : [
          {
            "id" : 0,
            "name" : "i"
          },
          {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "1"
          },
          {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "2"
          }
        ],
        "estimatedCost" : 681849.3200000001,
        "estimatedNrItems" : 170462
      },
      "warnings" : [ ],
      "stats" : {
        "rulesExecuted" : 19,
        "rulesSkipped" : 0,
        "plansCreated" : 1
      }
    }



    SLOW Query:

    arangosh [Uni]> stmt.explain()
    {
      "plan" : {
        "nodes" : [
          {
            "type" : "SingletonNode",
            "dependencies" : [ ],
            "id" : 1,
            "estimatedCost" : 1,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 1
          },
          {
            "type" : "EnumerateCollectionNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              1
            ],
            "id" : 2,
            "estimatedCost" : 17046233,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 17046232,
            "database" : "Uni",
            "collection" : "EAll",
            "outVariable" : {
              "id" : 0,
              "name" : "i"
            },
            "random" : false
          },
          {
            "type" : "CalculationNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              2
            ],
            "id" : 3,
            "estimatedCost" : 34092465,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 17046232,
            "expression" : {
              "type" : "compare !=",
              "subNodes" : [
                {
                  "type" : "attribute access",
                  "name" : "lastpaff",
                  "subNodes" : [
                    {
                      "type" : "reference",
                      "name" : "i",
                      "id" : 0
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "type" : "value",
                  "value" : ""
                }
              ]
            },
            "outVariable" : {
              "id" : 1,
              "name" : "1"
            },
            "canThrow" : false
          },
          {
            "type" : "FilterNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              3
            ],
            "id" : 4,
            "estimatedCost" : 51138697,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 17046232,
            "inVariable" : {
              "id" : 1,
              "name" : "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "type" : "CalculationNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              4
            ],
            "id" : 5,
            "estimatedCost" : 68184929,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 17046232,
            "expression" : {
              "type" : "compare ==",
              "subNodes" : [
                {
                  "type" : "attribute access",
                  "name" : "lastname",
                  "subNodes" : [
                    {
                      "type" : "reference",
                      "name" : "i",
                      "id" : 0
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "type" : "value",
                  "value" : "Kmp"
                }
              ]
            },
            "outVariable" : {
              "id" : 2,
              "name" : "2"
            },
            "canThrow" : false
          },
          {
            "type" : "FilterNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              5
            ],
            "id" : 6,
            "estimatedCost" : 85231161,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 17046232,
            "inVariable" : {
              "id" : 2,
              "name" : "2"
            }
          },
          {
            "type" : "ReturnNode",
            "dependencies" : [
              6
            ],
            "id" : 7,
            "estimatedCost" : 102277393,
            "estimatedNrItems" : 17046232,
            "inVariable" : {
              "id" : 0,
              "name" : "i"
            }
          }
        ],
        "rules" : [
          "move-calculations-up",
          "move-filters-up",
          "move-calculations-up-2",
          "move-filters-up-2"
        ],
        "collections" : [
          {
            "name" : "EAll",
            "type" : "read"
          }
        ],
        "variables" : [
          {
            "id" : 0,
            "name" : "i"
          },
          {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "1"
          },
          {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "2"
          }
        ],
        "estimatedCost" : 102277393,
        "estimatedNrItems" : 17046232
      },
      "warnings" : [ ],
      "stats" : {
        "rulesExecuted" : 19,
        "rulesSkipped" : 0,
        "plansCreated" : 1
      }
    }
```

Comment: I am struggling to reproduce the problem in 2.4.0. I have tried both the above queries plus variants that AND-combine the two conditions in the same `FILTER`. Can you provide the type of index(es) created for the collection, plus the execution plans for the above two queries? At least the interesting parts, i.e. whether they use an index or not. That would be helpful.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in 2.4.1 either. It may depend on the index definition. Any further info on this or the execution plans would help.

Comment: I have updated the explanation now, and inserted the execution plans ...

Comment: Ok, now I see. The slow query does not use an index, the fast one does. That absolutely explains the difference. I couldn't reproduce the problem before because I tried the original queries you posted, which both work fine. The queries in the detail example are different from the original queries: they use an equality filter and an non-equality filter, whereas the original queries used two equality filters. Looking into it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, conditions like the following disabled the usage of indexes even though an index could be used:

```
FILTER doc.indexedAttribute != ... FILTER doc.indexedAttribute == ...
```

Interestingly an index is used when the two conditions are put into the same `FILTER` condition and combined with `&&`:

```
FILTER doc.indexedAttribute != ... && doc.indexedAttribute == ...
```

Though these two statements are equivalent, they trigger a slightly different code path. The former will be AND-combining two existing `FILTER` ranges, the latter one will produce a range from a single `FILTER`. The case of AND-combination for the `FILTER` ranges was overly defensive and rejected both sides even if only a single side (in this case the one with the non-equality operator) could not be used for an index scan.

This has been fixed in 2.4, and the fix will be contained in 2.4.2. A workaround for now is to combine the two `FILTER` statements in a single one.

Comment: Sounds very good! I am looking forward to 2.4.2 and THANK YOU again for your perfect help here!

Comment: I also put together an explain mechanism that shows the execution plan in a more compact format. I hope this will make analyzing future queries a bit easier: http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2015/01/23/explaining-aql-queries-the-fancy-way/